# Meaning of サマんなんない?

Tags: words, slang

Here's the context: a loan shark has asked a yakuza to help him collect a loan. The yakuza came back with the money. The loan shark paid for the yakuza's trouble and then tried to give the yakuza a little extra but the yakuza was reluctant. Then the loan shark said:

> 本職のきみが金もないんじゃサマんなんねぇだろ
>
> source: 龍が如く0 誓いの場所 第一話, can be seen [here on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fV-G1_O0A8o#t=4m45s) at around 4:45 min.

I have no idea what サマ means. Could be slang or something since I can't find it in dictionaries. What is it and how does it work here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is no slang.  It should be in any dictionary.

[大辞林第三版・デジタル大辞泉　「さまになる」](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%A7%98%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B-511905#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88)

「サマ**ん**なんねぇだろ」＝

「[様]{さま}**に**ならないだろう」← "dictionary" form

「ん」 is the colloquial contraction for 「に」 here.

「なんねえ」 is the mostly-Kanto colloquial way of saying 「ならない」.

「様になる」 means "to look good", "to look proper", etc.

> 「様になんねぇだろ」 = "You wouldn't look good."